# Calculating the interest on a series of loans

Tags: c++, beginner, finance

I am a college student and started my first week of C++ and we were given an assignment to convert a Java program that calculate the interest on a series of loans given the amount of the principal, the annual interest rate, and the number of days in a sentinel loop into C++.

Here is what we were given:

> ```
> import java.util.Scanner;
> public class ex311
> {
> public static void main(String[] args)
> {
>     double principle, rate, interest;
>     int days;
>     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>     System.out.print("Enter principle (-1 to end):  ");
>     principle = sc.nextDouble();
>     while (principle != -1)
>     {
>         System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate (as a decimal):  ");
>         rate = sc.nextDouble();
>         System.out.print("Enter number of days:  ");
>         days = sc.nextInt();
>         interest = principle * rate / 365 * days;
>         System.out.printf("Interest is %.2f\n", interest);
>         System.out.print("\nEnter principle (-1 to end):  ");
>         principle = sc.nextDouble();
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

This is what I have for the C++ converted code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    double principle, rate, interest;
int days;
cout << "Enter principle (-1 to end)";
cin >> principle;
while (principle != -1)
{
    cout << "Enter annual interest rate(as a decimal)";
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Enter number of days";
    cin >> days;

    interest = principle * rate / 365 * days;
    cout << "Interest is "<< interest;
    cout << "Enter principle (-1 to end)";
    cin >> principle;
}
}
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to go about this, as in making my code more efficient. I am aware that I should not be using `void main`, but this is how we're being taught for the time being.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why someone would *teach* about using `void main`.  But at least you know that it's wrong.

Comment: I asked the same thing as well,but from what I was told today it's to just get the basics down. I am using the proper way while I practice on my own time.

Answer (score 5):

- [Do not represent monetary amounts as a decimal type; use an integer type instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149033/best-way-to-store-currency-values-in-c)
- [Try to avoid the use of `using namespace std`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)
- You could still allow the user to enter an interest rate and have the program convert it to a decimal, especially if the user doesn't know how to do this.
- You could just have `days`, `rate`, and `interest` declared or initialized within the loop.  It's usually best to have variables kept in as close scope as possible.

  Moreover, if you're going to "list" variables, have each one on a separate line.  This is easier to read and avoids the possibility of needing to scroll horizontally.